# SES not sending emails to own verified addresses even Test Email option

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

SES has been working fine for years. Normally via PHP applications running on EC2.

Today I noticed we stopped receiving emails sent to our own domains. These emails are verified in SES.

I then checked directly in SES and chose to 'Send a Test Email.' It works to gmail and other addresses but I never receive anything I send to one of our own verified emails. Same behavior from EC2.

The only change I made today was to the security group on EC2, but I can't see how that would impact 'Send a Test Email'

No error messages are received anywhere, the emails just don't arrive.

Any ideas?

***several hours later update***

Emails sent 10+ hours ago started to be delivered, however also received bounce-backs on others via SNS that shows:

```
{
   "notificationType":"Bounce",
   "bounce":{
      "bounceType":"Transient",
      "bounceSubType":"General",
      "bouncedRecipients":[
         {
            "emailAddress":"abc@abc.com",
            "action":"failed",
            "status":"4.4.7",
            "diagnosticCode":"smtp; 554 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes.<421 4.4.2 Connection closed unexpectedly>"
         }
      ],
      "timestamp":"2020-05-27T16:32:59.630Z",
      "feedbackId":"0101017256fad8b9-72c34b6e-fe92-4cd7-8ba5-2768d0f44cd4-000000",
      "reportingMTA":"dsn; a27-24.smtp-out.us-west-2.amazonses.com"
   },
   "mail":{
      "timestamp":"2020-05-27T00:38:50.000Z",
      "source":"abc@abc.com",
      "sourceArn":"arn:aws:ses:us-west-2:065803636095:identity/abc@abc.com",
      "sourceIp":"xxxxxxxx",
      "sendingAccountId":"xxxxxxx",
      "messageId":"01010172539149cd-3af0aa01-39ad-4498-8aa2-618f52dfabe6-000000",
      "destination":[
         "abc@abc.com"
      ],
      "headersTruncated":false,
      "headers":[
         {
            "name":"From",
            "value":"abc@abc.com"
         },
         {
            "name":"To",
            "value":"abc@abc.com"
         },
         {
            "name":"Subject",
            "value":"abc@abc.com"
         },
         {
            "name":"MIME-Version",
            "value":"1.0"
         },
         {
            "name":"Content-Type",
            "value":"text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
         },
         {
            "name":"Content-Transfer-Encoding",
            "value":"7bit"
         }
      ],
      "commonHeaders":{
         "from":[
            "abc@abc.com"
         ],
         "to":[
            "abc@abc.com"
         ],
         "subject":"abc@abc.com"
      }
   }
}
```

So, some messages being received very delayed and others are bounced back.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, which port are you connecting over. Also look at SNS notifications to acknowledge if your emails actually sent: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html

Comment: Port doesn't seem like the issue because it fails when sending on AWS using the Send a Test email option

Comment: Have you verified your records still exist in DNS? Also as mentioned above try enabling the SNS notifications

Comment: The addressess were verified on their own. Not via DNS. It still shows them as 'verified' I enabled SNS on your advice. I don't see how to trace individual messages but I did start getting some bounce-backs that say `action":"failed","status":"4.4.7","diagnosticCode":"smtp; 554 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes.<421 4.4.2 Connection closed unexpectedly>"}]`

Comment: @mokugo-devops I updated the original question

Comment: Is this emails to a specific domain or all domains?

Comment: @mokugo-devops It is to any domain that I have verified in AWS. It seems to work fine to external domains